# Using user specified pathname

Tags: python, forms, flask

I am creating a form and want to enable a user to specify a path.

I am trying to create a form with a field allowing the user to specify a pathname which will then go on to be used by a python function. At present I am just using a text form field in the HTML template:

```html
<br>
<label for="userpath">Path name for files:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="userpath" name="userpath" placeholder="Provide path name">
<br>
```

And then in my python script I am executing some code based on this user input

```python
from random import randint
from time import strftime
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, StringField, SubmitField

DEBUG = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'SjdnUends821Jsdlkvxh391ksdODnejdDw'

class ReusableForm(Form):
    userpath = TextField('Userpath:', validators=[validators.required()])

def actions(userpath):


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def userform():
    form = ReusableForm(request.form)

    #print(form.errors)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userpath=request.form['userpath']
        userpath = str(userpath)
        dest = os.path.join(userpath) 


        if form.validate():
            actions(userpath)

            flash('Actions being completed on: {} {}'.format(userpath))

        else:
            flash('Error: All Fields are Required')

    return render_template('userform.html', form=form)
```

However, it does not appear that I can specify a path this way. I am not sure if the use of '/' is altering functionality, however, when I instead put the path name directly into the python script everything works so I know it is something to do with how I get this information from the form

Comment: You have put `userpath` in quotes instead of using the variable in `os.path.join('userpath')`. This means that `dest` is being set to "userpath"! Try removing these quotes

Comment: Sorry Luke, that was a typo on my part. I haven't included the quotes in the script and it still doesn't accept user input. Thanks so much for the reply though :)

Comment: Add some logging and log the `request.form` variable in the `userform()` method and post that - you don't give us enough info

Comment: Sorry Mike, I'm fairly new to flask and adopted this from another example of using forms that was working. I have added some of the extra code at the beginning that I was using. I haven't detailed my whole actions function as it's lots of lines of code and if I input the paths myself as strings directly it works. Is that what you needed?

Comment: `os.path.join` joins multiple strings with slashes to create a path... passing one argument to it won't really do anything? https://code-maven.com/slides/python-programming/os-path-join

Comment: Hi Luke, yes I can see my misuse of os.pth now, thank you! Given that the user will probably input their path as a string with slashes how would be best to convert that into a pathname that can be used by a python function?